# How edit register in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I try edit the register in my firebase with this code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        findByCode: function(table, code, event, callback){
            var refFirebase = this.getInstanceFirebase(table);
            refFirebase.orderByChild("code").equalTo(String(code)).once(event, function(snapshot) {
                callback(snapshot);
            });
        },
        saveOrUpdate: function(table, object){
            var self = this;
            var isSave = !(object.update);
            var refFirebase = this.getInstanceFirebase(table);
            this.findByCode(table, object.code, 'value', function(objectDB){
                var objectExistsInDB = (objectDB && objectDB.val());
                if(objectExistsInDB && isSave){
                    alert('Já existe um objeto nax tabela "' + table + '" com o código: ' + object.code)
                    return;
                }

                if(!isSave) refFirebase.set(object)
                else refFirebase.push(object);
            });
        },
        delete: function(table, object){
            var refFirebase = this.getInstanceFirebase(table);
        },
        getInstanceFirebase: function(table){
            var authHandler = function(error, authData) {
                if (error) console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            }
            var login = '123@gmail.com',
                password = '123',
                token = '123';

            var ref = new Firebase("https://blazing-fire-2429.firebaseio.com/" + table);
            ref.authWithPassword({
                email    : login,
                password : password
            }, authHandler);
            return ref;
        }
    },
    render: function() {

    }
});
```

My db:

[image]

When squeegee **refFirebase.set(object)**  data from my db are overwritten. And only the last update data is displayed.

Whats a problem?

**UPDATE 1**

When use **refFirebase.update(object);**

Firebase include new register in root path:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the way `set` works. If you only want to set the keys that exist in `object`, you should use `refFirebase.update(object)`. See [the documentation for `update`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html).

Comment: Thanks for response. When use refFirebase.update(object). Firebase include new register in root path. Look my question now.

Comment: @EmirMarques If you want to create a child node, you should probably be using `push` instead. It's not clear from your question exactly what you're trying to do.